# Making overlapping submatrices

Tags: matrices

Is there anyway I can make a matrix like this?:

[image: I assure you, I need this]

Yes, that looks strange, but I assure you I actually need this.

The "column" and "row" numbers are actually some sort of physical index, and the non-zero entries are physically allowed transitions; one boundary condition forbids all transitions outside the submatrix with brackets []; another boundary condition forbids everything outside the submatrix with ().

I am trying to illustrate that all allowed entries can be written in the much smaller matrix, which is the overlap between the two.

Now I just use a png image like this, which I put together in Gimp, but it feels like this should be possible to do in latex using the various matrix environment. I can make the main matrix of allowed transitions like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
        &\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{matrix}\\%The indices on top, with an empty entry in front, the same width as the indices on the side
    \begin{matrix}0\\1\\2\end{matrix}%The indices on the side as a submatrix
    & \begin{vmatrix}%The main submatrix of allowed transitions
        a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & b & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & c & 0\\
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

Produces this:
[image: Only allowed transitions]

And I can insert one, or the other submatrix by doing this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
        &\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{matrix}\\%The indices on top, with an empty entry in front, the same width as the indices on the side
    \begin{matrix}0\\1\\2\end{matrix}%The indices on the side as a submatrix
    & \begin{vmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0\\
        0 & b\\
        0 & 0
        \end{bmatrix}%
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        c & 0
        \end{matrix}
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

which gives me

[image: boundary condition 0]

Or this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
        &\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{matrix}\\%The indices on top, with an empty entry in front, the same width as the indices on the side
    \begin{matrix}0\\1\\2\end{matrix}%The indices on the side as a submatrix
    & \begin{vmatrix}
        a &\begin{matrix}
            0 & 0 & 0
        \end{matrix}\\%
        \begin{matrix}
            0\\
            0
        \end{matrix}&%
        \begin{pmatrix}
            b & 0 & 0\\
            0 & c & 0
        \end{pmatrix}
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

Which gives me

[image: boundary condition 1]

Which is awful (The alignment of the numbers is way off), and I still have no way of combining the two.

So my question is, how do I make a matrix, containing multiple overlapping submatrices, preferably denoted by having different outlines () vs [], preferably while keeping the horizontal spacing between the numbers consistent? Preferably using only standard packages, though I am open to using some other packages to do this.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Just a thought: personally I'd do this by highlighting the submatrices with partially transparent coloured boxes, maybe with cross hatching or some other effect on the overlap area to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `{vNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,margin]
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-2}]
  \SubMatrix({2-2}{3-4})
\end{vNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: It works, but (as the NiceMatrix manual states) I needed to compile the document twice before I got the right result.